# Right syntax for a C++ non-type template template with a given type

Tags: c++, templates, non-type

I have a class templated over a non-type attribute pointer over a template type, here a `std::optional`.

```cpp
#include <optional>

class A
{
public:
  std::optional<int> i;
};

template <typename C, typename T, std::optional<T> C::*optionalPtr>
class OptionalHolder3
{
    void doStuff(C &c);
};

using OH3 = OptionalHolder3<A, int, &A::i>;
```

It works well but I was curious if I could make it easier to use, by reducing the number of required template arguments, but I can't find the right syntax:

```cpp
// Doesn't compile
template <typename C, template<class T> std::optional<T> C::*optionalPtr>
class OptionalHolder2
{};

// Doesn't compile
template <template<class C, class T> std::optional<T> C::*optionalPtr>
class OptionalHolder1
{};

using OH2 = OptionalHolder2<A, &A::i>;
using OH2 = OptionalHolder1<&A::i>;
```

Is this possible and how do I do it?

Comment: in your example one could simply remove the pointer to member because it isnt used. It is also not clear what you need `T` for

Comment: `template <auto optionalPtr> requires std::is_member_object_pointer_v<decltype(optionalPtr)> class OptionalHolder3`?

Comment: That actually depends on what you really intend to do with, so we'd need so the definition of `doStuff`. Maybe you could drop the `OptionalHolder` entirely by simply having `template <typename C, typename T>void doStuff(C& c, std::optional<T> C::*ptr);` and provide front-end functions for concrete types?

Comment: You need `<auto optionalPtr>` plus some SFINAE magic to make sure it is indeed a `std::optional<T> C::*` for some `T` and `C`.

Comment: By the way, what do you really want to achieve by that construct at all? Maybe we're talking about an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: My real use case is a Boost MSM actions and guards, with a std::future instead of an optional. `doStuff` is actually the guard function, which opens the future to check if it is valid. That's why I can't just create a function that will deduce its template arguments, because I give the class type to Boost MSM. I also don't have a choice on the signature of `doStuff`.
I am in C++17 so concepts are out of the question, and SFINAE would make it more complex than it is already.

Comment: just use `<auto optionalPtr>`, no need for SFINAE or concepts. If you want to provide an extra level of verification then you may add an extra `static_assert` verifying that `optionalPtr` is a required kind of pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `auto` (C++17) for that:

```
template <auto>
class OptionalHolder; // No definition

template<typename C, typename T, std::optional<T> C::*optionalPtr>
class OptionalHolder<optionalPtr>
{
    void doStuff(C &c);
};
```

concepts from C++20 might be used instead of that specialization, but it would require some traits to extract `T` and `C`.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Gc5K7obdf